# Facebook pixel tracking - where does the fbq code need to be placed?

Tags: facebook

I'm thinking this sounds daft , but i'll ask anyway.

We had a Facebook advert go out at the weekend, had lots of page views but no conversions.

With Facebook's pixel, does fbq('track, purchase, ...') need to be placed in the same script tag as the other tracking code, or can it appear later on in my code?

I ask because I'm working on a Prestashop website and the track part comes later on at the end of the page.

thanks.

Comment: No, as long as the pixel script initialized correctly, you can call fbq later on, that should not be a problem. // I can recommend the [FB Pixel Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) Chrome extension; it can help a lot in checking whether your implementation is correct.

Comment: use FB Pixel Helper to check if the pixels are working

Comment: Cheers Guys - will give it a go.